# MySQL Left join with grouping and date

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

As you can see on this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e40c2f/2), I have this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE reviews
    (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     `shop_id` int(11), 
     `order_id` char(255), 
     `product_id` char(32), 
     `review_time` int(11),  
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )
;
INSERT INTO reviews
    (`shop_id`, `order_id`, `product_id`, `review_time`)
VALUES
    ('10', '100', '1000', '1466190000'),
    ('10', '100', '1000', '1466276400'),
    ('10', '100', '1000', '1466462800'),
    ('20', '800', '8000', '1466249200')
;

CREATE TABLE tags
    (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     `shop_id` int(11), 
     `order_id` char(255), 
     `product_id` char(32), 
     `tag_time` INT(11) NULL,  
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )
;
INSERT INTO tags
    (`shop_id`, `order_id`, `product_id`, `tag_time`)
VALUES
    ('10', '100', '1000', '1466449200'),
    ('10', '100', '1000', NULL),
    ('10', '100', '3000', NULL),
    ('20', '800', '8000', '1469449200')
;
```

I need to get statistics by date showing how many reviews I have per date and how many were tagged and how many were not. I'm using this query:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(r.`review_time`), "%d.%m.%Y") AS review_submited_on,
  r.`shop_id`,
  COUNT(*) as total_orders,
  COUNT(*) as tagged_orders 
FROM
  reviews AS r
LEFT JOIN tags as t 
  ON r.`shop_id` = t.`shop_id` AND 
  r.`order_id` = t.`order_id` AND 
  r.`product_id` = t.`product_id` 
WHERE
    t.`tag_time` IS NOT NULL    
GROUP BY r.`shop_id`, r.`order_id`, r.`product_id`  
ORDER BY review_submited_on ASC
```

**UPDATE**
The expected result would look like this:

```
| review_submited_on | shop_id | total_orders | tagged_orders |
|--------------------|---------|--------------|---------------|
|         17.06.2016 |      10 |            3 |             1 |
|         18.06.2016 |      20 |            1 |             1 |
```

I created this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e40c2f/2) for demo.
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: What would the desired result look like? (Why does no one ever provide this?)

Comment: You wanna aggregate reviews and tags for each shop, order, product, or all three combined?

Comment: @Tin I want to see how many reviews were tagged from the total existing reviews. Please see the table I put in the question as of how the result should look like. Thanks

Comment: Now I have a questions. First row from your expected result table: total_orders should be 1? If you say 3, you're counting # reviews instead of # orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, and let me know if that is something you want.

```
SELECT review_submited_on, shop_id, total_orders, IFNULL(tagged_orders, 0) tagged_orders
FROM
    (SELECT shop_id, COUNT(DISTINCT shop_id, order_id, product_id) total_orders, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(review_time), "%d.%m.%Y") AS review_submited_on
    FROM reviews
    GROUP BY shop_id) review_counter
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT shop_id, COUNT(DISTINCT shop_id, order_id, product_id) tagged_orders
    FROM tags 
    WHERE tag_time IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY shop_id) tag_counter
USING (shop_id)
```

Result

```
| review_submited_on | shop_id | total_orders | tagged_orders |
|--------------------|---------|--------------|---------------|
|         17.06.2016 |      10 |            1 |             1 |
|         18.06.2016 |      20 |            1 |             1 |
```